# Counting text matches in sqlite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am querying several columns in a table for some words (essentially querying m text columns whether they contain n terms which are entered by the user), and I want to rank these rows by how many matches occur. 
So I have something like this query :

```
SELECT *, (COLUMN1 LIKE '%TERM1%') + (COLUMN1 LIKE '%TERM2%') + ... + (COLUMN1 LIKE '%TERMN%') + (COLUMN2 LIKE '%TERM1%') + ... + (COLUMNM LIKE '%TERMN%') AS SCORE 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE COLUMN1 LIKE '%TERM1%' OR ... OR COLUMNM LIKE '%TERMN%' 
ORDER BY SCORE DESC LIMIT 200;
```

But  this query does not seem to work all the time, sometimes all the results seem to have score 0, even when there are matches. Can anybody suggest what the problem is? I suspect it might be something to do with the type of result of LIKE operator and the type of score column.

Also, is there some better way of doing the same thing without generating this verbose query?

Answer (score 0):

yes there another way using code
try this

```
long cnt = countdata("COLUMN1 LIKE %TERM1%")
```

:

```
public Long countdata(String whereClause) {
        long count = 0;
        Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM TABLENAME WHERE " + whereClause, null);
        int numRows = c.getCount();
        c.moveToFirst();
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
            Log.i("Count", c.getString(0));
            count = c.getLong(0);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        c.close();
        return Long.valueOf(count);
    }
```